# SPListItemVersion determine which fields updated

Tags: 2013, splistitem, versioning, version

For out of the box, the version history will only display the updated fields. How can I determine whether a field has been updated for a specific version programmatically? My end goal is to display only modified fields per version

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
            SPListItem item = oList.Items[0];
            SPListItemVersionCollection versions = item.Versions;

            foreach (SPListItemVersion version in versions)
            {
                textToReplace += version.VersionId + " "
                    + version.VersionLabel + " "
                    + version.Url + " " 
                    + version["Division"] + " "
                    + version["Department"] + "<br/>";

            }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can find the updated fields by comparing the actual version fields with the version fields before.
Example code can be found here: http://charliedigital.com/2011/03/04/getting-version-changes-from-sharepoint/

Keep also a view on fields which are null and which contains equal strings. Hence I changed the foreach loop like this:

```
foreach (SPField field in currVersion.Fields)
{
    if (field.ShowInVersionHistory == false)
    {
        continue;
    }

    if (prevVersion == null)
    {
        iCntChanges++;
        //Console.Out.WriteLine("  > {0} changed to \"{1}\"",
        //    field.StaticName, currentVersion[field.StaticName]);
        continue;
    }

    // if both are null, avoid errors below
    if (currVersion[field.StaticName] == null && prevVersion[field.StaticName] == null)
    {
        continue;
    }

    // if one is null, avoid errors below and we have a difference found
    if (currVersion[field.StaticName] == null || prevVersion[field.StaticName] == null)
    {
        iCntChanges++;
        strFieldsChanged += ", " + field.StaticName + "(einer ist null)";
    }

    if (currVersion[field.StaticName].Equals(prevVersion[field.StaticName]))
    {
            continue;
    }

    if (currVersion[field.StaticName].ToString() == prevVersion[field.StaticName].ToString())
        continue;

    iCntChanges++;
    strFieldsChanged += ", " + field.StaticName + "(" + currVersion[field.StaticName].ToString() 
                                                + ", " + prevVersion[field.StaticName].ToString() + ")";

    //Console.Out.WriteLine("  > {0} changed from \"{1}\" to \"{2}\"",
    //    field.StaticName, previousVersion[field.StaticName], currentVersion[field.StaticName]);
}
```

Kind Regards
Ernst

Comment: Hi Ernst, theoretically this will work. I am trying to find a more optimal solution such as a property indicator instead of comparing everything. I'll not mark this as a solution but I'll give it an upvote so as to leave the question open for possibly better answer